# Unable to start apache2 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apache2, httpd.conf, ubuntu-16.04

i am trying to start apache2 but i am getting below error.

```
* Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
(specific information not available): AH00058: Error retrieving pid file /var/r AH00059: Remove it before continuing if it is corrupted.
Action 'start' failed.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some odd pid file path you have there, remove it as the message tells you and try to start again.

Worth checking if the path in use is correct.